# Naming an unknown amount of new instances for a class

Tags: c#, class

I am trying to develop a windows form application in which the user will set an unknown amount of "subcategories". How can I automate the naming of these new instances.

In case it helps here is what I am going for

```
private class Category
{
    int numberOfCategories = 0;

    Category(int categoryNumber)
    {
        numberOfCategories = categoryNumber;

        for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfCategories; ++i)
        {
            SubCategory *automateThis* = new SubCategory();
        }
    }
}
private class SubCategory
{
```

Thank you.

Comment: unused variable `automateThis`. What are you doing with the subcategories?

Comment: As seen in the first two answers, how do you plan on accessing your SubCategories later? That will determine the data structure to use, whether it be a List or a Dictionary. If the user is going to name the SubCategories themselves, for example, a Dictionary with the name as the key might be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you name them? It will create another problem - how would you access them?
Better approach is to create collection `List<SubCategory>` and in such a case you don't have to worry about naming objects.

In case you want to delete SubCategories - you may consider using Dictionary where string may be unique identifier for SubCategory.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `list<>` of the `SubCategory` objects and use `i` to increment.

Answer (score 0):

One solution

```
private List<SubCategory> _subCategories = new List<SubCategory>();
private class Category
{
    int numberOfCategories = 0;

    Category(int categoryNumber)
    {
        numberOfCategories = categoryNumber;

        for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfCategories; ++i)
        {
           _subCategories.Add(new SubCategory());   
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could use an array, or some other aggregate
If you want a name, use a dictionary. What is the name though?

After you comment

When? Do you know that before you create them? Are you loading them up from a file or a db?

Why do you need anthing more than a SubCategory having a Name property?